# Proving a monotonic subsequence exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, logic, combinatorial-number-theory

### CONTEXT

I have been studying about finding the limit of a sequence lately, and it becomes apparent that one way for a sequence to have limit is that it is monotonic and has a lower (or upper) bound. I, then, recognized that a sequence can also be convergent at many points.

And this problem comes to my mind. It is not any part of the convergent issue but rather a combinatoric one.

I had answered this, but I want to see if any of you do anything different.

Any solution is appreciated.

### PROBLEM

Let there be a numerical sequence consists of $(m\times n+1)$ numbers $a_1, a_2,a_3,...,a_{mn+1}$, with $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Prove that**:$\exists$ an increasing subsequence of $m+1$ numbers or a decreasing subsequence of $n+1$ numbers

Comment: This is a well-known result of Erdos and Szekeres. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem [that link may not work because of the hyphen, you may have to copy-paste].

Comment: Previous questions involving Erdos-Szekeres: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505556/example-of-erdos-szekeres-bound-being-tight and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284972/proof-for-erdős-szekeres-theorem-using-dilworths-theorem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659845/how-do-i-explain-erdos-szekeres-theorem-to-a-child and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079113/a-sequence-of-rs-1-real-numbers-has-an-increasing-subsequence-of-length-r and many others.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, this one is not that difficult. I mean I am a 10th Grader and I solved this **without** knowing anything about Erdos and Szekeres so can you find another way or elaborate your answers more?

Comment: I can I know whether I have found *another* way, if I don't know what *your* way is?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Check out my solution below please.

Answer (score 0):

**@Gerry Myerson** This is *my way* for the problem. I don't know if it has anything to do with **Erdos-Szekeres**, but still check this out.

### Solutions

Each number $x$ in the sequence belongs to some sub-sequences. Note that the sub-sequence have $\ge 1$ numbers.

With each number $x$, denote $P(x)$ as the longest ascending sub-sequence that includes $x$, and the number of numbers in $P(x)$ is k.

Thus, we have $\exists x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < ... < x_k = x$

Assume that for all x, we have $\vert P(x) \vert \le m \tag{1}$

Consider all the following sets: $A_i = \left\{x \vert P(x)=i \right\}; i=1,2,...,m$

Because we have $mn+1$ numbers, so according to the Pigeonhole Principle, there exists one set $A_k$ such that $\vert A_k \vert \ge n+1$

But with each number $a_i$ and $a_j$ belong to the same $A_k$, if, $i<j$ and $a_i<a_j$, then by definition, since $a_i$ and $a_j$ are already the largest numbers in their sub-sequences, $a_i=a_j$, which is a clear contradiction. Thus, the numbers in $A_k$ forms a descending sequence of $n+1$ numbers. $\tag{2}$

(1) and (2) $\Rightarrow$**Q.E.D**

### Post script...

While demanding that there is another approach to this problem, I think this is the most elementary and basic solution that any beginner at combinatorics can think of.

Still, I appreciate your ways of thinking and introduction of new theories that I haven't known.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Check this out